# MySQL | Sum Column If Different ID

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I'm trying to Sum column only if id is different.

I tried like this, but it is not working:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN 
             DISTINCT empLeaves.ApprovedLeaveID 
         THEN empLeaves.TotalLeavesTaken END) AS Total
```

What Would be the proper way to `SUM` it?

Here is the total query, I am working on:

```
SELECT 
      E.employee_id AS EmployeeID, 
      E.employee_code AS EmployeeCode,
      E.full_name AS EmployeeName,
      empLeaves.LeavesFromDate,
      empLeaves.LeavesToDate, 
      -- COUNT(empLeaves.ApprovedLeaveID) AS TotalApprovedApplications,
      ATT.`in_date` AS InDate, 
      ATT.`out_date` AS OutDate,
      SUM(CASE WHEN DISTINCT empLeaves.ApprovedLeaveID THEN empLeaves.TotalLeavesTaken END) AS Total
FROM employee E
LEFT JOIN `attendence` ATT ON ATT.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id`
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT 
                 LA.`leave_approval_id` AS ApprovedLeaveID,
                 E.`employee_id` AS EmployeeID,
                 LA.`approved_from` AS LeavesFromDate, 
                 LA.`approved_to` AS LeavesToDate,
                 DATEDIFF(LA.approved_to,approved_from) AS TotalLeavesTaken
            FROM leave_application APP
            INNER JOIN leave_approval LA 
                 ON LA.`leave_application_id` = APP.`application_id` AND LA.`trashed` = 0 AND LA.`status` = 2
            INNER JOIN employee E 
                 ON E.`employee_id` = APP.`employee_id` AND E.`trashed` = 0 AND E.`enrolled` = 1
            INNER JOIN ml_leave_type MLLT 
                 ON MLLT.`ml_leave_type_id` = APP.`ml_leave_type_id` AND MLLT.`trashed` = 0
) empLeaves ON E.`employee_id` = empLeaves.EmployeeID
WHERE
     E.`enrolled` = 1 AND E.`trashed` = 0
GROUP BY
     E.`employee_id`,empLeaves.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

When which ID is different from what?

In general, when you have a value in a field and you want to add them together except for those in a particular set of rows, you simply set the unwanted values to 0:

```
sum( case otherfield when somevalue then row.field else 0 end ) as SumOfValues
```

So when `otherfield` shows that this is the row you want included in the total, you expose the field you want to add (`row.field` in this example). Otherwise, you expose a zero. Of course, if the value you're testing is to find the rows you *don't* want in the total, just put the zero after the `then` and the field after the `else`.